# How can I check if a check box is checked in view page with razor in asp.net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new in `asp.net mvc` and write this razor code for show me check box component:

```
@Html.CheckBox("FlatFile",false)
```

I want write razor c# script to check if that check box is checked then work some thing, I don't want to write javascript or anything, I just want write c# razor script code for that purpose.

How can I write that?

Comment: You can't do it without js. Other way to achive it is to post form to controller with this input checkbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your checkbox code:

```
@Html.CheckBox("FlatFile",false)
```

Now you can use the CheckBox name (i.e., FlatFile) to do stuff in your controller like :

```
public ActionResult Something(IEnumerable<bool> FlatFile)
{
    if(FlatFile!= null) --you can give your condition here
    {
         --do something
    }
    else
    {
         --do something else
     }
}
```

A sample example:-

This is my controller code:-

```
public ActionResult test()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult test(bool FlatFile)
    {
        if(FlatFile==true)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Selected";
            return View();
        }
        else (FlatFile == false)
        {
            ViewBag.Message="Not selected";
            return View();
        }            
    }
```

This is my view code(i.e., test.cshtml):-

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("test", "User", FormMethod.Post,
new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<fieldset>
    <legend>Test CheckBox</legend>

   <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Select"):</td>
            <td>@Html.CheckBox("FlatFile", false)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Check" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@ViewBag.Message</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</fieldset>
}
```

Comment: thanks but something action not run when click on the checkbox in view page

Comment: I just added a sample example for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can check this using FormCollection in your controller action. 
try using below code:

```
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Index(FormCollection frm)
        {
            bool MyBoolValue = Convert.ToBoolean(frm["FlatFile"].Split(',')[0]);
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: What if it is for a foreach loop? for example, the checkbox in HTML is Html.CheckBox(item.Name, false) and in controller we need to check if it is checked or not?